# Hostid. What is it and is there a problem with hostid on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

What exactly is the hostid?  Is it equivalent to the Hwaddr / MAC address or is it a unique identifier that is derived from the Hwaddr addresses?

I am trying to activate the Maple mathematical software but it gives me an error stating that the software was unable to determine the hostid. I have followed all the instructions listed in the following help page from Maplesoft but with no luck so far.

http://www.maplesoft.com/support/faqs/detail.aspx?sid=32610

When I enter hostid into Teminal it outputs “007f0101” which is probably incorrect. I read that a hostid  is supposed to produce a unique identifier for each unix like machine but I have tried hostid on two different Ubuntu 12.04 installations and they both return the same “007f0101” sequence. Something is amiss I would reckon unless I have misunderstood what a hostid is.

Oh, this Ubuntu installation was done with the WUBI installer so it is technically on a virtual disc which resides in the Windows partition from what I gather. I have a feeling that may be a problem but that doesn' change the fact that the hostid was the same on two different computers, one of which was a standard installation.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be with regards to the hostid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`hostid` is your IP address in hex, byteswapped.

For example:

```
01234567 -> 23.01.67.45
```

Or in your case:

```
007f0101 -> 7f.00.01.01  = 127.0.1.1
```

Which is found in `/etc/hosts`. That's normal if your machine was installed using a `DHCP` assigned address.

A quick hack is to vi `/etc/hosts` and put in your IP address instead of 127.0.1.1.  But that is a hack... if your IP address changes at the next boot, your hostid will no longer match your IP.

The bottom line is that hostid sucks.

**Update:**

I wrote my own hostid script in perl/shell and put it in path first:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x\n",(split /\./,`ip addr list|grep " inet "|grep -v " 127.0"|head -1|cut -f1 -d/|rev|cut -f1 -d" "|rev`)[1,0,3,2]);
```

Notably, it doesn't fall back to using loopback if there are no other interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have three physical machines all three 12.04 (2 desktop, 1 server), all three AMD64, all three with the same hostid "007f0101".

It seems in the glibc implementation of gethostid (see man gethostid), the hostid is stored in the file /etc/hostid, which is by default absent in 12.04. If this file is non-existent, it then uses the localhost ipv4 address to generate the hostid. If you use DHCP, in the hosts file, localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1 on all machines, resulting in non-unique hostid's.

You could create the /etc/hostid file with random content to get a unique hostid.